# Most basic type in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a single root type that all other types inherit from in python? From doing basic trial-and-error, it seems this may be the type called `type`:

```
>>> None.__class__
<class 'NoneType'>
>>> None.__class__.__class__
<class 'type'>
>>> None.__class__.__class__.__class__
<class 'type'>
```

And also it seems like that is the only type for which the class of it equals itself.

Are there any other types that are more basic than the `type` type? If not, why is `type` the most basic type in python?

Comment: All types inherit from `object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'type' is something known as a *metaclass* in python.

metaclasses are a little different from classes. Like classes create instances of objects, metaclasses create instance of classes. Python is a little different than other languages when it comes to classes. In Python, a class is also an object. This *object* has the ability to create more objects so, it is a *class*.

But still, it's an object, and therefore:

1. you can assign it to a variable
2. you can copy it
3. you can add attributes to it
4. you can pass it as a function parameter

[This](https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/) is a good article that talks about it in more detail.
Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python) SO question could also be useful.

> Are there any other types that are most basic than the type type?

Yes, In fact, you can create your own metaclasses.
To do that, you have to create a class derived from the class 'type'. Refer to the links for a more in depth answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer at exact anwer at https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#objects.

In short, most basic type of all Python obejct is Class 'object'.

You can simply check this way in python console

```
>>> help(object)
Help on class object in module builtins:

class object
 |  The most base type


>>> issubclass(type,object)
True
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question